# is newKieSession thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, drools, kie

We used Drools kieSessions in our project. Many threads can create new kieSession. Sometimes thread can hang while creating session. Hence the question:

Firstly

1. is kieContainer.newKieSession thread-safe operation?
2. Can the reason of hanging be a dirty writing or reading the collection of kie sessions or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I checked in practice

```
newKieSession
```

isn't thread-safe operation.

Comment: I just checked for version 6.2.0.Final and 6.3.0.Final - it still isn't thread safe. Reference: https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/javadocs/org/kie/api/KieBase.html#newKieSession()

Comment: @Eugene did you find out what exactly is not thread-safe? I am trying to separate kie module/base/session/rule configuration from rule evaluation and keep those activities mutually exclusive (via a ReentrantReadWriteLock). So only a write thread can create new kieContainers while all rule evaluation (read only) accesses the kieContainer unsynchronized (using those `newKieSession`, `newStatelessKieSession` methods).. Ill post an answer below..

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any explicit statement in the drools documentation, but my understanding is that the `KieContainer` is thread-safe and even smart enough to (somewhat silently/magically) update itself (or rather its contained KieBases).

For all practical purposes (debugging/reading the source code) I think all the `KieContainer.newStatelessKieSession()` and the `KieContainer.newKieSession()` methods are thread-safe.

I am not 100% sure about the `updateToVersion()` and `updateDependencyToVersion()` methods and whether changing the kie container through those works in parallel with the `KieContainer.newStatelessKieSession()` and `newKieSession()` methods.

In our application we managed to separate the logic of modifying your rules (and modules, bases, sessions and their configuration) from the rule evaluation (which uses the `newKieSession` etc methods) and things seem to be fine so far, but I'd like to understand how you came to the conclusion that it isnt thread-safe.