# NullPointerExceptions when using multiple concurrent KieSessions

Tags: java, jboss, drools, redhat, jbpm

We are facing NullPointerExceptions while StatelessKieSession while it internally dispose in concurrent execution environment.

> *java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.drools.core.impl.StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.dispose(StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:395)
>           at org.drools.core.impl.StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.execute(StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:355)*

Sample code is

```
 public class ThreadExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService submitAsyncPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        Callable<Boolean> processor = new WorkerThread();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            submitAsyncPool.submit(processor);
        }
    }
}

    public class WorkerThread implements Callable<Boolean> {

    @Autowired
    StatelessKieSession kieSession;

    @Override
    public Boolean call() {

        // some code snippet

        kieSession.execute(input);

        // some code snippet

    }
}
```

This is only happening in concurrent execution of rules. `StatelessKieSessio`n is shared across multiple threads and executed concurrently. Other option is to create `StatelessKieSession` every time which I think very expensive operation.

Looks like this is defect in rules engine? Is there any workaround?

Note: We are using Drools 6.x

Comment: Drools KieSession is not Thread safe in nature either you have to use separate session per Thread or you have to synchronize execute the statement. Reference https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/javadocs/org/kie/api/KieBase.html#newKieSession()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is newKieSession thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807390/is-newkiesession-thread-safe)

Comment: @Prog_G - Thanks for response! Using separate session means initialize resources etc and will hit performance :( and same with making synchronized execution.

Comment: yeah. This way only you can use kieSession with multiThreading

Comment: There is a possible way suggested in below link can help to come out with this error. BUT that is doesnt look like good solution though.... https://github.com/mswiderski/jbpm-examples/issues/9

Comment: @Nishat Creating `kieservices` per thread is a heavy task. You can create `kiessesion` per thread that is what I told you to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolved above error by upgrading drools version fro 6.1.0.Final to 6.2.0.Final

Same testcase i have executed with 6.2.0.Final and no issues found.

Sound little strange but it resolved our issues.

I hope it may help others.