# Is building Kie sessions thread safe?

Tags: java, drools

We have some code that creates about 1500 Kie sessions in parallel and I got the impression that it is not thread safe. I checked all our code which is stateless and the last missing pieces in my puzzle is the following code:

```
public KieSession buildSession(Config configuration) throws InvalidConfigurationException {
    KieFileSystem kfs = this.kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

    addRules(config, kfs); // Stateless

    this.kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();

    KieBaseConfiguration kieBaseConfiguration = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieBaseConfiguration();
    kieBaseConfiguration.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);

    KieContainer kieContainer = this.kieServices.newKieContainer(this.kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase(kieBaseConfiguration);

    return buildSession(configuration.getHouseholdId(), kieBase);
}

public KieSession buildSession(KieBase kieBase) {
    KieSessionConfiguration kieSessionConfiguration = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieSessionConfiguration();
    kieSessionConfiguration.setOption(ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo"));

    KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession(kieSessionConfiguration, null);

    return kieSession;
}
```

We add the rules as strings to the file system. The documentation says:

```
However, since in this case the KieFileSystem doesn’t contain any pom.xml file (it is possible to add one using the KieFileSystem.writePomXML method though), Kie cannot determine the `ReleaseId` of the KieModule and assign to it a default one.
This default `ReleaseId` can be obtained from the KieRepository and used to identify the KieModule inside the KieRepository itself.
```

So my guess is that in this case as we do not have a pom file in the file system we would always use the default `ReleaseId` and have the equivalent of a temporary variable which is used to store the Kie module. Then two threads could override this variable which means that in some cases the method would return the wrong kie session for a configuration.

Is this correct? If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807390/is-newkiesession-thread-safe - says that it isn't.

Comment: I have seen it, but it is 4 years old and does not contain an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late answer.

My assumption has been actually correct, when you create a new KieFileSystem it is registered in the repository with the release id. When you do not specify a release id the default release id is used and you can override the file system of another thread. It is look a hashmap where all threads use the same key.

So what we did as to create our own release id and the final code looks like this

```
ReleaseId releaseId = new HouseholdReleaseId(configuration.getHouseholdId()...);

KieFileSystem kfs =
   this.kieServices.newKieFileSystem()
      .generateAndWritePomXML(releaseId); // Set the release id here.

// Do all the stuff with the file system.

KieContainer kieContainer = this.kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId); // Same release id.
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase(...);
```